# Azure Authentication only works for home page, not all pages in the blazor web assemble app

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, blazor-webassembly, microsoft-identity-platform

I am trying to implement Azure AD authentication and authorization for a blazor web assembly hosted app. The authentication is only working if I request the home page. If I directly try to access other endpoints in the app, it loads the content even though I am not signed in. I would like to be prompted to enter credentials if I try accessing any page in the app. I am thinking I need some additional code or settings, but not understand how and where to do it. Please help.

Comment: Please refer this link for more details regarding it: - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: I followed the same document. Doesn’t work as expected. Thank you.

Comment: You set `Authentication` in azure portal directly ? Or add code in your program ? Which knid of way you use ?

Answer (score 0):

•   I tried to create an Azure AD hosted Blazor web assembly app and integrate it with Azure AD authentication by using the github link below. It worked correctly for me as you can see in the snapshots below also: -

Github link : - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-blazor-server/blob/main/WebApp-OIDC/MyOrg/README.md

Application registered in Azure AD: -
[image: AAD app registration]

App build and execution in VS code: -
[image: App build in VS code]

Blazor web assembly Application running output: -
[image: App output]

Also, when I directly try to open a different page in the application after signing out, it requests me for signing into the application again as below: -
[image: Different page sign in]

Please check the URL for the above displayed page as below: -

https://login.microsoftonline.com/6b5fb116-315a-4e79-8923-49e5338f3b0c/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=e014b246-9de0-4e20-a5fc-98b44cd12d91&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44318%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=637762757113524173.ZTgxYmY1ODUtNGM4Yi00NWFmLWFiZDctOTNhNmJjN2NjNzdhYzhhZjcxNzYtNDhlZC00NGZiLTgyMjktNjhkYzQ2Yzk1NzY3&client_info=1&x-client-brkrver=IDWeb.1.3.0.0&state=CfDJ8BaRuiKB4iBEjoN1dXV_1w4a1v55GuR6GFNUs9Q8Eeq4tSHQDq3FoBQmyUn30VOR2HhpKUs-Nxhg9UUUzT8TTMtQyL-ZQRUVrYUSYhPNejtGIq_mmrmj3L5ubH9B6q0v1QjVzcTeaE70pgMHDCTgDY6p0viJPCbySeTU59hrW_aKfFFrs7HCrSaYWX2ZQYTZieIuip0YeKjowX7PzEXRh9Gotl0EcRessQPXOMu_b1IahUSwvOaBfoh-DyTqbNub6ZO18Y8d7chBLKB6LsTAH04-99eOKxF80kiYXNkqthNjQYWhhDjFkukoZO4FEQ_-tw&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.5.0.0&sso_reload=true

Thus, when you build a blazor web assembly app hosted in Azure AD, please ensure to include the ‘Require Authenticated user’ parameter in the ‘startup.cs’ file of the concerned application project as below to require the app to ask for sign in when you navigate to any page in the application: -

```
    ‘  {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    } ‘
```

[image: Required Authentication - Startup.cs]